# Clean ways to create lots of cubes in AFrame.io

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, voxel, aframe

I have a system, which reads SVG image, and then generates voxel world based on that data. Basically, the SVG image tells the program, where to put which block.

Up to now it worked for Minecraft, but I want to change it so that it create voxel-worlds in a browser-friendly way (i. e. so that people can look at the model without installing Minecraft and required infrastructure).

There will be lots of cubes there. One obvious method is to generate the HTML page with lots of `<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 0 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>` statements, but I assume it's not elegant and can lead to problems with large models.

What are my options in creating AFrame.io-based voxel worlds in an external (non-JavaScript) application? I seek a solution, which will work in a headless mode (i. e. I send the SVG file to a server and there it converts it to a AFrame.io voxel world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at examples like https://ngokevin.github.io/aframe-magicavoxel-projects/ using https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-magicavoxel-projects it might be enough for your needs.

As far as I understand either your merge to an object and get performance but no flexibility or you don't merge but expect a performance hit. Without measuring and having a rough estimation of both the size of your scene and your target platform I would say... try without merging or exporting first.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use MagicaVoxel. I rather want to know, how software like MagicaVoxel manages to export the models in an Aframe-compatible way.

Comment: MagicaVoxel exports to the standard obj + mtl format.

Comment: By "standard obj" format you mean this [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) ?

Comment: Yes exactly, basically a text file that lists the coordinates of the vertices and when put back by Aframe or another 3D engine shows a geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the template component: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-template-component/ . This way you can use for loops in HTML.

Or entity generator component: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-entity-generator-component . Pass it a mixin and it will create X number of entities using that mixin. Then you can combine with other components like layout or randomizer to customize

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of the template component and entity generator compared to displaying the OBJ file (as explained in the previous answer) ? Note that I want the solution to be able to work with voxel models with hundreds of voxels.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you could somehow convert SVG to OBJ beforehand. Perhaps by parsing it. I actually just re-read your question and my answer doesn't make sense for it, sorry. You could try creating a box for each voxel, and merging the geometries (check geometry component API) such that everything is one draw call.